# Nant - copy only modifiled files

Tags: nant

I'm looking for Nant script syntax that will copy from one folder to an other all files that were modified within last 5 days.

How I can cause to  to include only modified files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use robocopy. Robocopy has an option to exclude older files. See this link.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

You would then run Robocopy for a nAnt exec task.

Hope this helps

Shiraz

Answer (score 0):

The idea is quite simple:

When you need to copy files from folder 1 to folder 2 which are modified relative to each other:

```
<exec program="C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe" failonerror="false" >
  <arg line="${source} ${destination} /D /E /C /Q /H /R /Y /K" />
</exec>
```

However, if you need to check timestamp too, you would have to create some kind of filter. This you could do either in a batch file or writing your own console app.